# import of HttpSocket in Paypal in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, paypal, paypal-ipn

Well, here's what i got. I have a line of code here that imports HttpSocket in my CakePHP-paypal integration.

It is located in my /app/PaypalIpn/Model/DataSource/PaypalIpnSource.php. Here it is:

```
function __construct(){
    if (!class_exists('HttpSocket')) {
        if(App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http')){
            $this->log('http socket imported','paypal');    
        }
    }
        else{
            $this->log('http socket not imported','paypal');
        }
    $this->Http = new HttpSocket();
  }
```

By the way, my HttpSocket.php is located here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\wifidrivescanportal\lib\Cake\Network\Http\HttpSocket.php
```

So everytime i try to access this function in my HttpSocket.php:

```
public function post($uri = null, $data = array(), $request = array()) {
     //$this->log('entered post in http socket','paypal');
     $request = Set::merge(array('method' => 'POST', 'uri' => $uri, 'body' => $data), $request);
     return $this->request($request);
}
```

via this line of code inside my PaypalIpnSource.php:

```
function isValid($data){
    // .... other codes
    $response = $this->Http->post($server, $data);
    return $response;
}
```

nothing happens. It doesn't log anything despite that i indicated it to log something particularly in some portions in /app/PaypalIpn/Model/DataSource/PaypalIpnSource.php

Answer (score 0):

Debug the raw response data in the HttpSocket class. In 1.3 I had a few cases in the past were I had the same issue with this class.

Try http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/http-socket/#l-292 debug($this->request['raw']) after this line.

The raw data might contain something that the 1.3 class does not pick up.

Comment: thanks for the response burzum, however, i believe the problem lies in the concept that i am not loading/importing/calling the HttpSocket properly... i guess so  :(

Comment: alright: when i enabled the $response else portion, well it did let me entered the else part which says:  "HTTP Error in PaypalIpnSource::isValid while posting back to PayPal"

Comment: You guess? Well you should debug and paste your stack trace here. I'm more or less sure it's not missing the HttpSocket because if it would it would show a fatal error that the class is missing.

Comment: got it solved burzum.. I'll always put that in mind that whenever HttpSocket is missing, it would show a fatal error. Would that be the same thing if other sockets are missing as well?

Answer (score 0):

Well here's what I did these line of codes

```
function isValid($data){
    // .... other codes
    $response = $this->Http->post($server, $data);
    return $response;
}
```

I made it this way:

```
function isValid($data){
    // .... other codes
    return $this->Http->post($server, $data);
}
```

Not so certain with the difference but it worked out this way. Once I finished my paypal integration in cakephp, i'll make sure i'll provide a tutorial for beginners like me. Hope I could help that way. My next goal is to do the encryption using ppcrypto.